# How to avoid mapping errors with Linq Expressions in Methods that create compiler generated display classes?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design

When I put a Linq expression into a domain class method that is being mapped by Entity Framework's Code First approach it causes a compiler generated display class to be created and then a mapping error occurs because the display class is not being mapped.

> ...+<>c__DisplayClass5' was not mapped. Check that the type has not
>   been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or
>   NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined
>   as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit
>   from EntityObject.

The expression I use that causes the issue in a method is:

```
UniqueIds.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdentifierType.Name == keyword);
```

I map types where:

```
.Where(x => x.Namespace != null
                  && !x.IsAbstract
                  && !x.IsEnum
                  && x.Namespace.StartsWith("<removedprefix>.Domain")
```

<sub>Note I don't actually use "removedprefix", I just don't want to reveal the namespaces for privacy reasons.</sub>

How do I use Linq expressions in domain class methods without getting the above error?

EDIT:  I want to solve the problem without disabling lazy-loading, of course.

Comment: not sure to understand the question but, does `DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` prevents the problem ?

Comment: @tschmit007 - I think that would fix the immediate problem, but that would disabled lazy loading, which would be overkill, throwing the baby out with the bathwater.   I'm trying to figure out how I'm supposed to configure EF code first to allow for linq expressions in methods.

Comment: If I well understand you have to use a DAO object between your proxy class and your display class, that his consider the displayclass as a DAO. That alse mean populat the DAO by hand that is, at the hand, equivalent to an eager loading. That's the response I get facing the same problem in a wcf context.

Comment: Domain entities != Persistence entities. Your problem is an example why using ORM entities as domain entites is wrong. Besides, DDD means that we don't care about the persistence when we model the domain.

Comment: @MikeSw While it's true that sometimes it's nice to use separate Persistence entities, ORMS like Fluent Nhibernate mean that you don't have to have separate persistence entities.  While I agree that from an absolute DDD purist point of view one might create separate persistence entities, in the .net world it's pretty common practice not to.  But the Domain/Persistence entity question is not really what I'm trying to figure out.  How do I configure EF code first to map a class with a linq expression in a method without failing?

Comment: It's not about purism it's about SoC. Only if you have an anemic domain you would use the ORM entities directly. And that common practice is bad practice. It's much harder to maintain an app where ORM is so entrenched in the domain. You always have to fight the ORM which is a PERSISTENCE detail. I'm really curious what you'll do if you won't be able to get EF to behave in this case. Would you tamper with the Domain object to fix a persistence problem?

Comment: @MikeSW - Ultimately I agree with you, but if you've ever used Fluent Nhibernate most, if not all of the persistence details can be hidden when the conventional setup of the ORM, truly.  I'm trying to see if such is possible with Entity Framework.  So that I don't have to waste time with creating nearly one-to-one persistence objects, which is difficult to justify to less knowledgeable developers and bosses.  But I may ultimately start creating persistence objects if I cannot solve this problem.  I'm waiting for the need to justify the creation of persistence objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread is a bit old, but I've just got the same problem. As the types Linq generates are "Nested and Private", and usually your mapped classes aren't, you could modify your filter like this:

```
.Where(x => x.Namespace != null
            && !x.IsAbstract
            && !x.IsEnum
            && !x.IsNestedPrivate //Not nested and private
            && x.Namespace.StartsWith("<removedprefix>.Domain")
```

I hope this still helps.

Comment: So this solution worked for you?  That's cool.  I learned to check the orm after I added any linq statements to a domain object, which makes this seem like a fairly large design failure on microsoft's part. I'll give your suggestion a try the next time I'm messing with that stuff.

Comment: I tested this briefly and so far so good, I'll see if it makes any trouble.